# ios How to convert asynchronous methods into synchronization methods

Tags: ios, asynchronous, synchronization, block

I want to convert a asynchronous method into a synchronous method ,as following:

```
- (NSString *)sendDataSynchronized:(NSData *)inputData {
    __block NSString *retData;
    [self sendData:inputData Callback:^(NSString *backData) {
        retData = backData;
    }];
    int delay = 10;
    NSTimeInterval ti = 0.2;
    int i = delay/ti;
    while (i > 0) {
        if (retData != nil) {
            break;
        }
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:ti];
        i--;
    }
    return retData;
}
```

but it's not nice method.

Comment: show us the `sendData:Callback:` method, if that is asynchronous, you need to change that function to be synchronous

Comment: sendData:Callback: is a asynchronous method ,send something and the result in the callback block.

Comment: well, why cant you make that synchronous instead of trying to do what you posted in the question? seems like you are making the problem more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: its much easier to convert synchronous methods to asynchronous than the other way round, so get your base sendData method to be synchronous, then try make another method to make it asynchronous instead, can use GCD's `dispatch_async` to do this quite easily

Comment: sorry, this question is duplicate, I have seen a better way. use dispatch_semaphore  can solve my question . Thank you.